# No response when trying to install instrument-control package in octave

Tags: octave, pkg-file, no-response

I am running raspbian on a Raspberry-Pi 2 B. I am trying to install the instrument-control package in octave 3.6.2.Initially I got a mkoctfile missing error: 
[Installing octave package in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262754/installing-octave-package-in-ubuntu) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=955385

With 'sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev' this problem was solved.

However, when I try to install the instrument-control package in octave with: 'pkg install -forge instrument-control' nothing is happening, the command prompt underscore is just flickering as if it is processing something, but nothing happens for at least half an hour (I didn't try longer). I tried running octave as superuser, but the same thing happened.

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me out on this.

NB This is my first post here, and am not a super-experienced computerist so please tell me if I need to provide more information in any form.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It turned out that it actually takes longer than 30 minutes to compile all the necessary files, so you just have to wait longer... When using -verbose this becomes apparant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that it actually takes longer than 30 minutes to compile all the necessary files, so octave is actually doing something. You just have to wait longer. When using -verbose this becomes more clear.

Comment: Thanks, `pkg install -forge -verbose control` can be used to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 0):

The downloading process might be hanging.

As a workaround, you can download the instrument-control package [there](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/octave/instrument-control-0.2.1.tar.gz?download).

Put it in your directory on the raspberry.

And then, in octave launched from the same directory, issue

```
pkg install instrument-control-0.2.1.tar.gz
```